# Avoidance receives warning message in Log10 operation

Tags: python, numpy

How can I avoid getting warning message when I execute the following code?

```
from numpy import inf
a = np.array([0.2,0.2,0.3])
b = np.array([0.3,0.0,0.1])
a = np.log10(a)
b = np.log10(b)
b[b == -inf] = 0
a[a == -inf] = 0

calc = a+b
```

The warning message received:

```
divide by zero encountered in log10
```

The code should yield the following result:

```
array([-1.22184875, -0.69897   , -1.52287875])
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972493/ignoring-negative-values-when-using-np-logarray/24972602

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the message with `np.seterr`:

```
from numpy import inf
a = np.array([0.2,0.2,0.3])
b = np.array([0.3,0.0,0.1])
with np.seterr(divide = 'ignore'):
    a = np.log10(a)
    b = np.log10(b)
b[b == -inf] = 0
a[a == -inf] = 0
    
calc = a+b
```

If you want to not ever calculate `log(0)`, you'll need to work around it as in the dupe target:

```
calc = np.zeros_like(a)
a_ = a.astype(bool)   #False when 0
b_ = b.astype(bool)
np.add.at(calc, np.nonzero(a_), np.log10(a[a_]))
np.add.at(calc, np.nonzero(b_), np.log10(b[b_]))
```

Both of these *only* get rid of errors from `a, b == 0` and not errors from `a, b < 0`